# MySQL LOCATE - ¿Qué comunidades autónomas contienen el nombre de una de sus provincias?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, sql

Tengo una tabla con las comunidades y provincias de España y quiero hallar qué comunidades autónomas contienen el nombre de una de sus provincias.
Creo que debo utilizar el comando locate pero no se como utilizarlo.
Alguien me pude guiar un poco para realizar la consulta?
Adjunto aquí el dataset:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Sin un esquema de la tabla es complicado, pero voy a suponer que tienes un campo `provincia` y un campo `comunidad` en la tabla `tu_tabla`

```sql
SELECT LOCATE(provincia, comunidad) AS contiene from tu_tabla;
```

Si "contiene" es mayor a zero, es que en el campo `comunidad` existe contenido el valor de `provincia`.

Mas info aquí: [W3CSchool](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_locate.asp)

Edito:
Sólo aquellos registros donde la comunidad autónoma contiene el nombre de una de sus provincias:

```sql
select * from provincias where LOCATE(provincia, comunidad) > 0;
```

Aunque tengas diferentes registros con la misma CA, sólo se muestra el registro de la provincia que está dentro del nombre de su CA, con lo que no deberías tener duplicados

Comment: He probado con ese código y solo me arroja números. te he adjuntado en el enunciado el dataset para que puedas observar mejor la estructura de la tabla.

Comment: No es posible acceder a tu enlance, ya que apunta a tu servidor local. Podrías poner una captura o algo así?

Comment: Acabo de añadir una captura al enunciado

Comment: Si claro, este resultado te dice si `provincia` está dentro de `comunidad`, que es lo que preguntabas.
Si lo que quieres es mostrar la tabla provincias, con sólo aquellos registros donde la comunidad autónoma contiene el nombre de una de sus provincias, la SQL hay que trabajarla un poco:

Te lo preparo en una nueva respuesta pq aquí no queda bién formateado

Answer (score 0):

Aunque has puesto un enlace a tu `localhost` que no es accesible por nosotros, creo que estás planteando una pregunta muy básica de `sql`. Corrígeme si no es así: mostrar la 
comunidad autónoma (debe ser en singular) de una provincia concreta.

Si tenemos una tabla tal que `Geografia`

```
Comunidad     Provincia
Galicia       Lugo
Galicia       Pontevedra
...           ...
Andalucía     Málaga
Andalucía     Granada
...           ...
```

Para encontrar la comunidad de la provincia de Granada debemos hacer

```
SELECT Comunidad from Geografia where Provincia = 'Granada';
```